# Let $u, v \in \mathbb C$, and $1<p\leq 2$ show $(|u| + |v|)^p + |\,|u|-|v|\,|^p\leq |u+v|^p + |u-v|^p$

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

Let $u, v \in \mathbb C$ and $1<p\leq 2$, so $(|u| + |v|)^p + |\,|u|-|v|\,|^p \leq |u+v|^p + |u-v|^p$

I'm trying to follow the proof of "A weak Parallelogram Law for $l_p$, W. L. Bynum and J. H. Drew"

My attempt:

Let $a = |u|$ and $b = |v|$.
If I write the right side as $f(t) = (a^2 + b^2 + 2ab t)^{p/2} + (a^2 + b^2 + 2ab t)^{p/2}$ for $t \in [-1,1]$. Then

$$f'(t) = ab p ((a^2 + b^2 + 2ab t)^{(p-2)/2} - (a^2 + b^2 + 2ab t)^{(p-2)/2})$$

The only critical point is $t = 0$. So we have

$$f(1) = f(-1) = (a+b)^p + (a - b)^p = (|u| + |v|)^p + |\,|u|-|v|\,|^p $$

$$ f(0) = 2(a^2 + b^2)^{p/2} $$

Well, as $p-2 \leq 0$, we have that in $(-1,0), f' >0$ and in $(0,1), f'<0$.
Then, $f$ has minimun at $1$ and $-1$.

My problem: 1. I'm not sure why I can write the right side as the function $f$. Because, if I write $|u + v|^p = (|u+v|^2)^{p/2} = (|u|^2 + |v|^2 + 2Re<u,v>)^{p/2}$. I can't see why I can change $2Re<u,v>$ for $2|u||v|t$ with $t \in [-1,1]$